# Large Realm file size due to RealmObject relationships

Tags: java, json, realm, android, gson

First of all, thanks for producing such a great product. Realm is fresh.

My question is simple. I have JSON to consume that looks like this: (put this link in Postman or some other JSON pretty-printer) http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/91.

I'm consuming this JSON with GSON and parsing all works fine. However, when I copy my POJO created from this JSON to Realm using Realm#copyRealmOrUpdate, the file size gets ridiculous. I'm certain it has something to do with the RealmList fields below:

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private int weight;
private int height;
private int order;
private int base_experience;
private boolean is_default;
private String name;
private String location_area_encounters;

private Sprite sprites;
private NamedResource species;

private RealmList<NamedResource> forms;
private RealmList<Stat> stats;
private RealmList<Ability> abilities;
private RealmList<Type> types;
private RealmList<Move> moves;
```

These fields could potentially have more RealmList's inside of them of RealmObjects. I believe this is what's causing my Realm file to grow out of proportion. If I annotate those RealmList fields with @Ignore, my file size is absolutely tiny (I haven't seen it go more than 1MB). However, if there is no annotation, it quickly reaches into the 10MB+ range.

Solutions I've thought of:

1) Use Gson's TypeAdapter to turn those RealmObjets inside of the RealmList into Strings. So instead of holding onto a RealmObject that has a String inside of it, just hold on to the String. However, TypeAdapters can be ugly and hard to maintain, so I don't want to go down that route.

2) Keep the fields with @Ignore and only query for them when I need them. However, I'd like to reduce the amount of network calls to as few as possible, as sometimes the database I'm using could be slow or just down.

3) Use a different mobile database. I've spent a good amount of time integrating Realm with my code and I'd like to not go down this path.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to compact your Realm?

Comment: Calling that method doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: ....no, you get a large file size if you don't close your Realm instance on the background thread. You need to close the Realm instance on the background thread when you're done with it.

Comment: I have. I call Realm.close () in on destroy of my Activity.

Comment: There's no question it's due to the model relationships. Again, when I annotate those RealmList fields with @Ignore, there's no problem. When I remove that annotation, the size of the Realm explodes.

Comment: How does your `Type` look like? If it doesn't have a PK, maybe you are creating a new `Type` every time when you add it to the list.

Comment: How big is the JSON blob pulled from the server? Realm allocate filesize in incremental steps, so if you have 1 MB of data without the lists, 5 MB with the lists, you might just hit a Realm threshold where we allocate more disk space (10 MB).

Comment: My type looks like this:

      "slot": 2,
      "type": {
        "url": "http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/type\/15\/",
        "name": "ice"
      }

Comment: As to the file size, a naive test (copy json text to text file and see how big that file is) says it's 128K. I understand the json is big, my wondering was if there were recommended ways to reduce the size when copied to Realm.

Comment: It sounds a bit strange if a 128K json file should result in a 10 MB file. Note that Realm is a MVCC database, so forgetting to close Realm instances on background threads could result in inflated filesizes. The problem would most likely be more visible with a bigger object graph (like when you add the RealmLists). With regard to strategies for minimizing file size, then links to other objects would affect the filesize, but only very minimally, so it would not be worth trying to structure your model classes around it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm closing Realm instances as they become unnecessary i.e. in Activity#onDestroy. Christian, could we talk further privately so we can get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Sure, feel free to email me at cm@realm.io or open an issue on our Github page https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues